# I can't find my Flutter app cached data on my phone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, android-camera

So I'm creating  an app using flutter in which i'm in need of the Phone Camera. In order to do so, i have added the package `camera 0.10.3+2` to my project. The following is the code of the screen that i'm having some trouble in

```
// ignore_for_file: file_names

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:prototype/constants.dart';
import 'package:prototype/main.dart' as main;
import 'package:prototype/tempPhoto.dart';


class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String id ="MainScreen";

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  XFile? imageFile;
  late CameraController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(main.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((Object e) {
      if (e is CameraException) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case 'CameraAccessDenied':
          // Handle access errors here.
            break;
          default:
          // Handle other errors here.
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 80,
              child: Container(
                decoration: kcustomContainer,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                      style: kButtonStyleAppBar,
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5,vertical: 10),
                        child: Text("Filters",style: kButtonTextStyleAppbar),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 150.0,
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: kCPGreenLight,width: 2.0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: kCPGteenDark, width: 3.0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: kCPWhite,
                          hintText: "Product name",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          iconColor: kCPGreenMid,
                        ),
                        onSubmitted: (value){
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                      style: kButtonStyleAppBar,
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5,vertical: 10),
                        child: Text("History",style: kButtonTextStyleAppbar),
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.more_vert,
                        color:kCPWhite,
                        size: 30,),
                      onTap: (){

                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (!controller.value.isInitialized) const Text("Camera Error")
            else Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                    width:double.infinity,
                    child: CameraPreview(controller)
                )
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 80,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Container(
                decoration: kcustomContainer,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        style: kButtonStyleAppBar,
                        child: const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5,vertical: 10),
                          child: Text("Mes Promos",style: kButtonTextStyleAppbar,),
                        ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          if(controller.value.isInitialized) onTakePictureButtonPressed();
                          },
                        style: kButtonStyleAppBar.copyWith(shape:  MaterialStateProperty.all<CircleBorder>(
                            const CircleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(width: 0,color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0))
                            )
                        ),),
                        child:  Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                          child: Text("Scan",style: kButtonTextStyleAppbar.copyWith(fontSize: 20),),
                        ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                      style: kButtonStyleAppBar,
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5,vertical: 10),
                        child: Text("Mes Recommandation",style: kButtonTextStyleAppbar,),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );



  }

  Future<XFile?> takePicture() async {
    final CameraController cameraController = controller;
    if (!cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      print('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }

    if (cameraController.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      print("taking photo !!!!!");
      final XFile file = await cameraController.takePicture();
      return file;
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
  void _logError(String code, String? message) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('Error: $code${message == null ? '' : '\nError Message: $message'}');
  }
  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    _logError(e.code, e.description);
    showInSnackBar('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }

  void showInSnackBar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }
  void onTakePictureButtonPressed() async {
    await takePicture().then((XFile? file) async {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imageFile = file;
        });
        if (file != null) {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>TempPhoto(path: file.path)));
          showInSnackBar('Picture saved to ${file.path}');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

here is the output of the Code :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyIIm.jpg)

And after clicking the Scan button(in the photo above), the app sends back the path of the image in a Toast. The path format is as follows `/data/user/0/com.examlple.prototype/cache/(photoname).jpg`.

But no matter what i did i couldn't find this folder in my `Internal Storage` of my phone. I even checked `Android/data/` and it wasn't there. So what can i do to check if it actually saved the picture and how can i view it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the plugin saves the file in the app memory cache. you can verify this by looking at your app size in your phone settings.
I personally use https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver (gallery_saver) to save camera files to gallery/photos which is handy.